# Generate rectangle with variable dimensions in CSS with inner gradient background

Tags: html, css

i have some variables on PHP who gain values from 0 to 100. I want to develop a simple graph system that draw a horizontal rectangle given the number (0, 1 , 50 and soo). Also i want to add some gradient to the background, doing this in php is complicated and i dont want more load in my server, so i know this is possible in css, but im not a css developer. So if any body can help me with this. In this page (http://www.answerbag.com/) you can se how i want the rectangle, in the results of the pool section in the middle of the above page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's very simple since you know the width.  Since you probably want the full spectrum of the gradient to show, you probably want to resize the gradient image by using a css `#score1 { width: 30px }`  on that `<img id="score1" src="blue_gradient.png">`  Then later on, you can use one of the many rounder corner methods to add the round corners to it.